# MySQL Random Result: Not Random, Ignoring latter end of table

Tags: php, mysql, random

I have a piece of code that selects a random ID from a MySQL table and displays the result (text):

```
        $text_result = mysql_query("SELECT text FROM `text` WHERE id >= (SELECT FLOOR( MAX(id) * RAND()) FROM `text` ) ORDER BY id LIMIT 1;");
    $text = mysql_fetch_array($text_result);
    echo "<div class='text'>" . $text{text} . "</div>";
```

I noticed when I was first adding columns that the results returned seemed weighted towards the lower IDs, but now I've added more (around 50) it seems pretty much only results from the first 25% of IDs get displayed

Anybody have any ideas as to what could be causing this? I'm pretty lost

Many thanks and apologies if I've missed something obvious

Comment: "_seems pretty much_" or "_has been empirically tested_" ?

Comment: rand() is not perfect, but a simper solution would be to do `order by rand() limit 1` instead of using it in the where clause.  You might find the mysql docs on their rand function useful for more info.. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using this, found [here](http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/36709-the-mysql-sticky/#entry178450):

```
SELECT
*
FROM
tablename AS t1
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT
ROUND(RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM tablename)) AS id
) AS t2 
ON
t1.id >= t2.id 
ORDER BY
t1.id ASC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Seems to be working well.

```
order by rand() limit 1
```

Worked too, but a slow loading time

Thanks all. Still curious as to what could have caused the problem if anybody knows.

Answer (score 4):

Try this query:

```
SELECT text 
FROM `text`
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

**Example:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aee9d0/1